# Exact Differential Equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve this equation so far, since the partial derivative respect to $x$ and $y$ are not exact, I have to find the $u(x)$ to make them exact

$e^x \cos(y)dx+\sin(y)dy=0$

Partial derivative of $y = e^x\sin(y)$

partial derivative of $x = -\sin(y)$

Now i have to find the $u(x)$ to make them exact

$u(x)(e^x\sin(y))=u'(x)(-\sin(y))+u(x)(-\sin(y))$

$u(x)\sin(y)(e^x+1)=u'(x)-\sin(y)$

$u(x)(e^x+1) = \frac{du}{dx} - 1$

$(e^x + 2)dx = \frac 1 u du $

$e^x + 2x = \ln(u)$

$u = e^{e^x + 2x}$

this $u(x)$ is too strange to make them exact...

If anyone can help to understand why it doesn't work.....

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I properly understand the problem; so forgive me if I am off topic.

It seems to me that you try to solve $$e^x\cos(y)dx+\sin(y)dy=0$$ This is a separable equation that you can write $$e^x dx=-\frac{sin(y)}{\cos(y)} dy$$ So, integration of both sides gives $$e^x+C=\log (\cos (y))$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make this equation exact, it's seperable. First subtract $sin(y)dy$ to get 
$e^x\cos ydx=-\sin y dy$
Then divide both sides by $\cos y$ to get 
$e^xdx=-tanydy$.
Proceed to integrate both sides.